# Python: Cache values of descriptors

Tags: python, descriptor

I would like to clarify some things about Python's descriptors. I want to add a property to my class with some complex set/get mechanics and cache those calculated values inside the descriptor object. A simplified example looks like this:

```
class Pro(object):
    """My descriptor class"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value


class Something(object):
    """My simple class"""
    pro = Pro()

a = Something()
a.pro = 1

b = Something()
b.pro = 2

print(a.pro, b.pro) # At first, I've expected them to be 1 and 2
```

I thought somehow that `pro` attribute would be unique instance of `Pro` for every instance of `Something`, obviously I was wrong. Looks like I should use something like `instance._value` instead of `self.value` inside `__set__` and `__get__`, but I've really hoped to hide everything inside `Pro` class. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property/0.1.5)?

Comment: @Lemming, looks pretty neat, thanks, but I was hoping to solve this with standard library only :)

Comment: Fair enough. Btw, as most python packages this one is open source. The [actual code](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property/blob/master/cached_property.py) is fairly small and the non-threading version doesn't need any extra packages.

Comment: The source was interesting, thanks, haven't seen it until now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're setting the attribute on Pro's instance which is going to shared by all instances of `Something`. To fix this you should set an attribute on the individual instance of `Something`, one way to do that is to use a metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if isinstance(v, Pro):
                # add an _ in front of the name
                v.name = '_' + k
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class Pro(object):

    def __get__(self, ins, typ):
        return getattr(ins, self.name)

    def __set__(self, ins, val):
            setattr(ins, self.name, val)

class Something(object):
    """My simple class"""
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    pro = Pro()

a = Something()
a.pro = 1

b = Something()
b.pro = 2
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> a.pro, b.pro
(1, 2)
>>> a.__dict__
{'_pro': 1}
>>> b.__dict__
{'_pro': 2}
>>> a.pro = 100
>>> a.__dict__
{'_pro': 100}
```

---

> So there is no way around making hidden attributes in Something
>   instances, right?

No, there is. You can store a dictionary in `Pro`'s instance that stores all the values related to each instance of `Something`. For example if `Something`'s instances are hashable then you can do something like this using [`weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary). The `WeakKeyDictionary` will make sure that that once a `Something`'s instance has no references left then it is garbage collected immediately which is not possible with a normal `dict`:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class Pro(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, ins, typ):
        return self.instances[ins]

    def __set__(self, ins, val):
        self.instances[ins] = val

p = Pro()

class Something(object):
    """My simple class"""
    pro = p

a = Something()
a.pro = 1

b = Something()
b.pro = 2

print a.pro, b.pro

print p.instances.items()
del a
print p.instances.items()
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
[(<__main__.Something object at 0x7fb80d0d5310>, 1), (<__main__.Something object at 0x7fb80d0d5350>, 2)]
[(<__main__.Something object at 0x7fb80d0d5350>, 2)]
```

Comment: So there is no way around making hidden attributes in `Something` instances, right?

Comment: If you want to 'cache' the value for an instance, somewhere that value has got to be associated with the instance.  Python attributes basically do that by using the __dict__ dictionary of the object.  You could reverse it by having a dictionary in the description with the instance as the key, but the basic problem remains that you need a mapping of instance to value or vice versa

Comment: @AntonMelnikov Definitely that is possible as well, see the update.